# Recent job searches doesn't work correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Go to jobs within SO and make sure you clear your **Your Recent Searches**:

[image]

Once you've cleared your search this div should disappear like so:

[image]

(PS: creepy guy on featured company on that screenshot)...

Now in the location select **Allows Remote** (dont click Search just yet):

[image]

Now click **search**

Notice no **Your Recent Searches** section is created:

[image]

Now without doing any changes just click **search** again...

[image]

Comment: If it helps tested on latest version of chrome - I didn't test with IE because I hate that darn browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was definitely working, but just differently to how you might think; it was always one behind. The premise being that why would you need a recent search entry for your *current* search?

But I agree, it's not exactly intuitive, so I've changed it to give immediate feedback.

Thanks for the report! But not for that font ;)